# Remove a specific character from a text file

Tags: javascript

I have a program that removes a character from a string and it works fine what I was trying to add was to make the program read a text file with multiple lines of text and remove the specific character if the character exists in the first position of every line. How can I implement this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Example:
22Orange
22Banana

would become:

Orange
Bannana
```

```
//something like this but this only works if I have a single line string
var aStr = fs.readFileSync('filePath', 'utf-8')
var bStr = aStr.replace(/^22+/i, '');
console.log(bStr)
```

Comment: You can't edit files using JS

Comment: @Rojo The asker is probably using Node.js.

Comment: @iota oh thanks I forgot about that. Well, that's what tags are for :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the global (g) and multiline (m) flags.

```js
let str = `22Orange
22Banana`;
console.log(str.replace(/^22/gm, ''));
```